# How do i trigger Argo job using java clients

Tags: java, automation, argo

How do I trigger Argo's job using java clients?Tried below libraries but had no luck

```
compile 'io.unikzforce:argo-java-client:0.1__v2.3.0-rc2'
compile "io.argoproj.workflow:argo-client-java:v3.1.0"
compile "io.argoproj.workflow:argo-client-java:1-SNAPSHOT" 
implementation group: 'io.fabric8', name: 'kubernetes-client', version: '5.10.2'
```

I tried adding the above as maven dependencies but it's not working.am unable to import argoproj